# Segmentation fault in one fgets implementation but not another, similiar implementation

Tags: c, fgets

I'm trying to understand the reason behind this problem; I have two very similar implementations of fgets in two separate programs. One of them works without any problems, the other causes a segmentation fault. The only difference between the two programs that I can see is the the one which works doesn't take any command line arguments, while the one which doesn't work does.

Is anyone able to help me understand the difference? I understand that you can't use fgets for something which you haven't allocated memory for, so then why would the first example work fine?

Thanks very much!

The working code (irrelevant parts missing):

```
int main(){
    char *s;
    while((fgets(s,100,stdin))){
        if (evaluate_checksum(s)){
            printf("%s",s);
        }
    }
}
```

The not-working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    sscanf(argv[1],"%d", &a);
    sscanf(argv[2],"%d", &b);
    sscanf(argv[3],"%d", &c);
    sscanf(argv[4],"%d", &d);

    char *line;
    long u1;
    long v1;
    long u2;
    long v2;

    while ((fgets(line,100,stdin))){
      printf("%s", line);
      char *endptr = line;
      u1 = strtol(line,&endptr,10);
      v1 = strtol(entptr,&endptr,10);
      u2 = strtol(endptr,&endptr,10);
      v2 = strtol(endptr,&endptr,10);
      printf("%ld, %ld, %ld, %ld",u1,v1,u2,v2);
    }

}
```

Comment: In the first example, you got lucky, and `char *s` pointed to somewhere innocuous.

Comment: Undefined behaviour means ***anything***. Sometimes it crashes straight away. Sometimes it seems to work. Sometimes it seems to work, and then crashes half an hour later. Sometimes it seems to work, and then multiplies all your calculations by 1000 for no apparent reason, and then you get fired because your boss thinks you went 1000 times over budget. (Well, hopefully not the last part)

Comment: This is calling fgets, not implementing it.  ("Implementing a function" means to write the body of that function).

Answer (score 4):

Both versions exhibit undefined behavior since you are reading data into memory that you haven't acquired. In the first case, it is not apparent right away. In the second case, it is apparent right away. Trying to make sense of their behavior is not fruitful.

Answer (score 2):

instead of using char pointer to store string, you should use char array.